# Twitter Oauth Callback Override Failing

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

So I have setup a twitter application so that people can reply to tweets inside my own app. I have a callback URL and when I do not try and override it everything seems to go fine. However Now I am having a problem getting the override of the callback to work the app runs on multiple sub domains and servers based on what stage of development it is in and I would like to override the callback to the current url.

When I do override the callback and twitter attempts to send the User back to that page I get to a page that says "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!"

and the URL looks something like this

https://twitter.com/oauth/http%3A//127.0.0.1/authtwitter%3FtwitterCallback?oauth_token=VALUE&oauth_verifier=VALUE

and Here is my Python code using this library for the oauth: https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

```
    #SETUP TWITTER AUTHORIZATION OBJECT
    request_token_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
    access_token_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
    authorize_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'

    consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer)

    #get request token
    callbackURL = urllib.quote("%s?twitterCallback" % self.request.url)

    resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST", body=urllib.urlencode({'oauth_callback':callbackURL}))
    if resp['status'] != '200':
            raise Exception("Invalid Response %s." %resp['status'])

    request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

    tmpldict['callbackURL'] = callbackURL
    tmpldict['oauth_token'] = request_token['oauth_token']  
    tmpldict['twitauthurl'] = "%s?oauth_token=%s" % ( authorize_url, request_token['oauth_token'] )                               

    qargs=urlparse_qs(self.request.url,True,False)

    if 'oauth_verifier' in qargs:
            oauth_verifier = qargs['oauth_verifier'][0]
    else:
            oauth_verifier = None

    if oauth_verifier:
            token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
            token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)

            client = oauth.Client(consumer,token)

            resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "GET")
            access_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
```

Current Flow for User

Click authorization URL

Hit Allow Access on Twitter

Twitter Displays: Redirecting you back to the application

Cannot Find page with URL like the example above.

Comment: I don't think Twitter lets you override the callback URL.  That said, you shouldn't be getting a 404. This is happening after authorization is done?

Comment: They allow it http://milindshakya.tumblr.com/post/4208580364/overriding-twitters-default-callback-url-using-oauth talked to a Twitter employee about it but thread went stale. It should work if you use POST in the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few quick things...

Your URLs are old and outdated and don't function as well as the proper URLs. Use SSL and the api subdomain:

- https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
- https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
- https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

It's unclear to me looking at this code whether you're performing header-based OAuth or querystring-based OAuth. I recommend header-based OAuth -- it dramatically separates concerns and makes it easier to discover wrongness when it happens.

Make sure that when you send your dynamic oauth_callback value to the oauth/request_token step that it's correctly percent-encoded. Also, make sure you have a placeholder HTTP-based callback on your application record on dev.twitter.com/apps

Comment: Thank You! Could you link me to an example or provide one of what distinguishes Header-based Oauth.